# React-native - How to keep fetch file uploading when terminate app(closing by home button) or change other app?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am making camera ios app(just after take a photo and upload) by using react-native.
However, I have a one problem. When I upload a photo directly to server, (most of photo size is over 1MB~2MB) this fetch post time is a little slow so that whenever I terminate app(by using home button) or use other app(changing), fetch post is failed and disconnected. (If I wait for response in app active status, It is easy to success.)

How to keep the file upload fetching during app closing status?

Maybe, Should I use react-native-background-fetch? I am a little complicated in this library.

Thanks to read :).

Comment: do you use react-native only or you are using expo?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-upload maybe this is what you need.

Comment: I've used react-native-background-fetch for this. Had no problems.

Comment: @m1sh0 This library is really so cool! Thanks! It good working!

Comment: The answer of the question is this library :) https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-upload

Comment: I will be happy if you mark my answer as a right one :)